# How does ddply split the data?

Tags: r, plyr

I have this data frame.

```
mydf<- data.frame(c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),c("e","e","e","e","e","e")
                  ,c(1,2,3,10,20,30),
                  c(5,10,20,20,15,10))
colnames(mydf)<-c("Model", "Class","Length", "Speed")
```

I'm trying to get a better understanding on how ddply works.

I'd like to get the average length and speed for each pairing of model and class.

I know this is one way to do it: `ddply(mydf, .(Model, Class), .fun = summarize, mSpeed = mean(Speed), mLength = mean(Length))`.

I wonder if I can get the mean using ddply and without specifying it one at a time.

I tried `ddply(mydf, .(Model, Class), .fun = mean)` but I get the error

> Warning messages: 1: In mean.default(piece, ...) :   argument is not
>   numeric or logical: returning NA

What does `ddply` pass on to the function argument? Is there a way to apply one function to every column using `ddply`?

My goal is to learn more about `ddply`. I will only accept answers will `ddply`

Comment: In your first example, you're calling `summarize`, which expects a frame; the follow-on arguments (`mSpeed`, ...) are then arguments to `summarize`, so a resulting call might be `summarize(x, mSpeed=mean(Speed), mLength=mean(Length))`. In your second call, you are trying to pass a full frame to `mean`, when it really only wants a vector. I don't know why you would prefer *"specifying it one at a time"* (as it will not be any faster), but `ddply(mydf, .(Model, Class), .fun = summarize, mSpeed=mean(Speed))` is one at a time.

Comment: My point is that mSpeed only gets me the mean of speed. What if mydf had 20 numeric columns. Can I use it to get the mean of each of those columns, split by Model and Class

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using `dplyr` and the `summarize` function.

```r
library(dplyr)


mydf<- data.frame(c("a","a","b","b","c","c"),c("e","e","e","e","e","e")
                  ,c(1,2,3,10,20,30),
                  c(5,10,20,20,15,10))
colnames(mydf)<-c("Model", "Class","Length", "Speed")

#summarize data by Model & Class
mydf %>%  group_by(Model, Class) %>% summarize_if(is.numeric, mean)


#> # A tibble: 3 x 4
#> # Groups:   Model [3]
#>   Model Class Length Speed
#>   <fct> <fct>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 a     e        1.5   7.5
#> 2 b     e        6.5  20  
#> 3 c     e       25    12.5
```

<sup>Created on 2019-04-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Please see my update to the post. I'd like to do it with `ddply`.